# Creating JSON table from SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json, phpmyadmin

I want to create a JSON table from the results of a SQL query. I tried the query on phpMyAdmin and it is correct (I get the data that I want) but then when I try to convert it to a JSON table using the code below, the result is a table with the correct structure but non of the values.

```
/* select all moches from the table moches */
$query="SELECT municipio, SUM(moche) AS moche FROM moches GROUP BY municipio";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

     $rows = array();
     $table = array();
     $table['cols'] = array(

       array('label' => 'Municipio', 'type' => 'string'),           
       array('label' => 'Cantidad total en moches', 'type' => 'number')

                );

     foreach($result as $r) {

                      $temp = array();

                      //Create the different states

                      $temp[ ] = array('v' => (string) $r['municipio']); 

                      // Total de moches

                      $temp[ ] = array('v' => (int) $r['moche']); 
                      $rows[ ] = array('c' => $temp);


                    }

      $table['rows'] = $rows;

      // convert data into JSON format
      $jsonTable = json_encode($table);
```

Comment: Sorry for any cringe-worthy terminology, I'm fairly new at this. JSON string is what I meant to say.

Answer (score 2):

phpMyAdmin permits to export in JSON format, maybe this can help you.

Answer (score 1):

nitpick: there's no such thing as a "json table". There's JSON strings, which are plaintext strings that represent a data structure in some other language, e.g. javascript.

Your problem is that you're trying to loop over a mysqli result handle. That's generally a single **ROW** of data, not the entire result set.

You should have something more like:

```
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

$temp = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
    $temp[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($temp);
```