# Smarter way to create JSON response from Mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, node.js

I have this code on my Node.js server side:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({ host: 'localhost', user: 'SOMEUSER',
    password: 'SOMEPASSWD', database: 'SOMEDB'});

exports.all = function(req, res){
    if (connection) {
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM planing GROUP BY linea, fecha, turno ORDER BY linea, fecha, turno;', function(err, rows, fields) {
            if (err) throw err;

            var datuak = [];


            console.log(rows);
            for(var i = 0, l = rows.length; i < l; i++) {

                //iterate row array to generate needed JSON format?
            }


            res.contentType('application/json');
            res.write(JSON.stringify(datuak));
            res.end();
        });
    }
};
```

Witch this query, I need to generate this JSON:

```
[
    {
        "linea": 1,
        "egunak": [
            {
                "fetxa": "2014/05/26",
                "turnoak": [
                    {
                        "turno": 1,
                        "ordenes": [
                            {
                                "ref": "3CI00001"
                            },
                            {
                                "of": "OF000013"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "turno": 2,
                        "ordenes": [
                            {
                                "ref": "3CI00001"
                            },
                            {
                                "of": 112233
                            },
                            {
                                "ref": "3CI00001"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "turno": 3,
                        "ordenes": [
                            {
                                "ref": "3CI00001"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "fetxa": "2014/05/27"
            },
            {
                "fetxa": "2014/05/28",
                "turnoak": [
                    {
                        "turno": 1,
                        "ordenes": [
                            {
                                "ref": "3CI00001"
                            },
                            {
                                "of": "OF200013"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "turno": 2,
                        "ordenes": [
                            {
                                "ref": "3CI00001"
                            },
                            {
                                "of": "OF232233"
                            },
                            {
                                "of": "OF289977"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "turno": 3,
                        "ordenes": [
                            {
                                "ref": "3CI00001"
                            },
                            {
                                "of": "OF200000"
                            },
                            {
                                "ref": "3CI00001"
                            },
                            {
                                "of": "OF200000"
                            },
                            {
                                "ref": "3CI00001"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "fetxa": "2014/05/29"
            },
            {
                "fetxa": "2014/05/30"
            },
            {
                "fetxa": "2014/05/31"
            },
            {
                "fetxa": "2014/06/01"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "linea": 2,
        "egunak": [
            {
                "fetxa": "2014/05/26"
            },
            {
                "fetxa": "2014/05/27",
                "turnoak": [
                    {
                        "turno": 1,
                        "ordenes": [
                            {
                                "ref": "3CI00002"
                            },
                            {
                                "of": "2OF000013"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "turno": 2,
                        "ordenes": [
                            {
                                "ref": "3CI00001"
                            },
                            {
                                "of": "2OF2233"
                            },
                            {
                                "ref": "3CI00001"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "turno": 3,
                        "ordenes": [
                            {
                                "ref": "3CI00001"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "fetxa": "2014/05/28"
            },
            {
                "fetxa": "2014/05/29",
                "turnoak": [
                    {
                        "turno": 1,
                        "ordenes": [
                            {
                                "ref": "3CI00001"
                            },
                            {
                                "of": "2OF200013"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "turno": 2,
                        "ordenes": [
                            {
                                "ref": "3CI00001"
                            },
                            {
                                "of": "2OF232233"
                            },
                            {
                                "ref": "3CI00001"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "turno": 3,
                        "ordenes": [
                            {
                                "ref": "3CI00001"
                            },
                            {
                                "of": "2OF200000"
                            },
                            {
                                "ref": "3CI00001"
                            },
                            {
                                "of": "2OF200000"
                            },
                            {
                                "ref": "3CI00001"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "fetxa": "2014/05/30"
            },
            {
                "fetxa": "2014/05/31"
            },
            {
                "fetxa": "2014/06/01"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

and this is the data:

```
   id  linea   fecha   turno  ref       of
    3   1   2014-05-26  1   3CI00001    OF000013
    4   1   2014-05-26  2   3CI00001    112233
    6   1   2014-05-26  3   3CI00001    
    7   1   2014-05-27  NULL        
    8   1   2014-05-28  1   3CI00001    OF200013
    9   1   2014-05-28  2   3CI00001    OF232233
    11  1   2014-05-28  3   3CI00001    OF200000
    14  1   2014-05-29  NULL        
    15  1   2014-05-30  NULL        
    16  1   2014-05-31  NULL        
    17  1   2014-06-01  NULL        
    18  2   2014-05-26  NULL        
    19  2   2014-05-27  1   3CI00001    2OF000013
    20  2   2014-05-27  2   3CI00001    2OF2233
    22  2   2014-05-27  3   3CI00001    
    23  2   2014-05-28  NULL        
    24  2   2014-05-29  1   3CI00001    2OF200013
    25  2   2014-05-29  2   3CI00001    2OF200013
    27  2   2014-05-29  3   3CI00001    2OF200000
    30  2   2014-05-30  NULL        
    31  2   2014-05-31  NULL        
    32  2   2014-06-01  NULL
```

I´m thinking to iterate on the rows and use if statements to generate a multimensional array witch I´ll convert to JSON, but is there any smarter o faster way to do that?

thanks in advance

Comment: try MongoDB database :)

Comment: how? I can do that if it is necesary

Comment: mongodb (http://www.mongodb.org/) is nosql document database, it solves problems like this very easy. And one more point. MongoDB is default database for nodejs. It works with javascript queries.

Comment: something like this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18665602/creating-json-table-from-sql-query/18665698#18665698 or as Nikolay said, go with mongodb.

Comment: I think I´ll go with MongoDB, this way I can learn and work with it. Can you @NikolayLukyanchuk answer my question to close it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try MongoDB database (mongodb.org) .MongoDB is nosql document database, it solves problems like this very easy. And one more point. MongoDB is default database for nodejs. It works with javascript queries.